# android: passing bundle changes type of object

Tags: java, android, bundle

I have stumbled onto a problem with an android app im writing.

Activity 1 looks like this:

```
// other code here:     
bundle.putString("MyKey" , My_Large_String_containing_HTML);
Log.d(tag + " - TEST" , "tmp CLASS:" + bundle.getString("MyKey").getClass());
Log.d(tag + " - TEST" , "tmp FETCHED:" + bundle.getString("MyKey"));


// make new intent, stuff it with bundle
Intent Activity2Intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);

Activity2Intent.putExtras(bundle);
Log.i(tag, "Bundle stuffed.. preparing to make a new screen...");

startActivityForResult(Activity2Intent, 0);
```

Activity 2 looks like this:

```
// other set up code
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

My_Large_String_containing_HTML = bundle.getString("MyKey");

/* throws an exception above
*
* WARN/Bundle(976): Key description expected String but value was a [Ljava.lang.String;.  The default value <null> was returned.
*
* WARN/Bundle(976): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:

* WARN/Bundle(976): java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String;
* WARN/Bundle(976):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1040)

*/
```

TLDR; I have a string, with HTML (usually) in it.  I need it to be available in a second activity.  I put it in a bundle; add a bundle to an intent.  Fire off the intent, and get the bundle.
i TRY to get the string from the bundle, but i get an exception saying that my *array* cant be gotten.

I never did anything with an array :/

So what's my problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: your coding style/format is very non-standard and therefore bad.  please fix :(

Answer (score 1):

You just put extras straight into the intent:

```
Activity2Intent.putExtra("MyKey", My_Large_String_containing_HTML);
```

Then to get the extras, you have to grab the bundle from the intent:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
My_Large_String_containing_HTML = bundle.getString("Mykey");
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few *hours* of debugging, I finally found out what the problem was.

Let me explain:
"MyKey" was a string constant from a 3rd class.

Class3:

```
static protected final String My_Static_string_key = "description";
```

Activity2:

```
My_Large_String_containing_HTML = bundle.getString(Class3.My_Static_string_key);
```

Activity1:

```
bundle.putString(Class3.My_Static_string_key , My_Large_String_containing_HTML);
```

I tried to store and retrieve all sorts of strings with that key; long, short, with HTML, with no HTML...etc. Nothing worked!

Then i changed the key.  Instead of using Class3.My_Static_string_key as the key to store and retrieve by,

I hard-coded it to the string stored in Class3 - "description".  this *still failed*.

last ditch attempt to fix: 
I changed the hard coding of the string to "BOB"

It worked!

I changed the string in my Class3 and it *still* works.

tldr: it was the *key* i was using.  for some reason, the string i was using broke things.  i changed the string in the key and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 Activity2Intent.putExtra("MyKey" , My_Large_String_containing_HTML);
    startActivity(Activity2Intent);

    //To receive from another Activity

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String result=bundle.getString("mykey");
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that i already tried this.

Same issue.  I'm not sure what the deal is, but i think my string is being improperly serialised when added to the bundle.  Attempts to pull it form the bundle after the bundle has been passed to the new Activity fail because it was not properly packed.

I'll just have to make my own Parcel class and try it that way, i guess.